# How can I add and transform images using React Native for Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch, reactjs-native

With the HTML5 canvas, one can `transform()` elements (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_transform.asp) for the general purpose multitool, and convenience methods let you do helpful subsets of a generic transform, like `rotate()`, `scale()`, and `translate()`.

**XY question variant of what I ask:** How can I treat an Apple Watch's display like an HTML5 canvas?

**Better way of asking:** I want to display images like clock hands and a back face (yes, I know this might not get into the app store) that involves repeated transforms, or positioning and then rotation around a point. What should I be reading / doing?

Thanks,